# java threads common questions

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some questions about java threads:

1. if I have a class that runs a number of threads when one thread reaches to exit(1) command line will it exit the thread or the whole application including the other threads?

2.how can I make one thread notify all other threads that run from the same class to stop?

3.does using synchronized make only one thread ,regardless his source in the code, to do this part of code?

4.if I am running a thread in java using run() if I call a method from inside the run() does this still running as a thread or it is not allowed?

Comment: 4) Are you asking whether it is impossible to call a function in a thread?

Comment: One question per stackoverflow post only, please. Also, this sounds as if you didn't google your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I have a class that runs a number of threads when one thread reaches to exit(1) command line will it exit the thread or the whole application including the other threads?

A call to `System.exit(1)` will terminate the calling thread **and** all other threads. It is the most brutal way of ending a Java program, namely completely shutting down the JVM, and should *rarely* be used at all.

> how can I make one thread notify all other threads that run from the same class to stop?

Not at all. If you have references to the other `Thread` objects, you can call `Thread#interrupt()`, but whether or not the other threads check their interrupted status or reach a place where they may throw an `InterruptedException` is left to them.

> does using synchronized make only one thread ,regardless his source in the code, to do this part of code?

Intuitively yes. However, when there is a `wait()` in this block, then the corresponding lock (that is, the object that was `synchronized` on) will be released and can be acquired by other threads.

> if I am running a thread in java using run() if I call a method from inside the run() does this still running as a thread or it is not allowed?

When a thread calls a method, then the same thread also *executes* this method (silently wondering how else it should be...)

Answer (score 2):

1) Only if thread are daemons, application will not wait to close even if they are running.

Example: comment or not the `setDaemon(true)`

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Launcher(parent).start();
    }

    public static class Launcher extends Thread {
        public Launcher(final String name) {
            this.setName(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.err.println(getName() +  is starting);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                new Waiter(child  + i).start();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.err.println(getName() +  is no more sleeping);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.err.println(getName() +  is stopping);
        }
    }

    public static class Waiter extends Thread {
        public Waiter(final String name) {
            super(name);
            super.setDaemon(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.err.println(getName() +  is starting);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(12000);
                System.err.println(getName() +  is no more sleeping);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) To force the stop, you can use different approach, different patterns. Sorry to not have THE solution. You can take a look at : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html

3) Yeah, it's the goal of synchronized.

4) It depends what you do but basically, calling a method do not launch another thread, except if  the methods does it.